# Using fstream to open a file that is created only during runtime

Tags: visual-c++, file-io, fstream, stdstring

I'm using Visual C++ 6.0 and I'm trying to use fstream to open and read a file that is created only during runtime. This file is written by another function running on another thread, and my program will keep trying to "open" the file until it can be opened, i.e. after it's created, then read 3 numbers from it and execute the rest of its code.

The file `test.txt` has the content

```
1
3
4
```

My program that polls and opens the file is as follows:

```
ifstream fin;
std::string tfile, snum1, snum2, snum3;
long int num2, num3;

tfile.assign(argv[1]);
printf("Begin prog %s\n", tfile.c_str());

fp: fin.open(tfile.c_str(), ifstream::in);
if (fin.is_open())
{
   printf("fin is open\n");
   getline(fin, snum1);
   getline(fin, snum2);
   getline(fin, snum3);
   num2 = atol(snum2.c_str());
   num3 = atol(snum3.c_str());
   printf("snum1 = %s\n", snum1.c_str());
   printf("num2 = %ld num3 = %ld\n", num2, num3);
   fin.close();
}
else
{
   printf("Cannot open file %s\n", tfile.c_str());
   fin.close();
   Sleep(500);
   goto fp;
}

remove(tfile.c_str());
printf("End of prog\n");
```

I executed the program by

```
test_prog.exe "C:\test.txt"
```

and waited about 3 seconds before putting the `test.txt` file into `C:\`

My output was

```
Begin prog C:\test.txt
Cannot open file C:\test.txt
Cannot open file C:\test.txt
Cannot open file C:\test.txt
Cannot open file C:\test.txt
Cannot open file C:\test.txt
Cannot open file C:\test.txt
fin is open
snum1 = 
num2 = 0 num3 = 0
End of prog
```

The `test.txt` file disappears after I refresh the `C:\` folder.

So the values for snum1, num2 and num3 are all wrong, as if the file was not read correctly.

If I put a `while fin.good()` loop after `printf("fin is open\n");` for that entire block (until printing the values of num2 and num3), then I get

```
Begin prog C:\test.txt
Cannot open file C:\test.txt
Cannot open file C:\test.txt
Cannot open file C:\test.txt
Cannot open file C:\test.txt
Cannot open file C:\test.txt
Cannot open file C:\test.txt
fin is open
End of prog
```

How can I correctly read a file that is only created during runtime?

ETA:
I've also added a

```
if (fin.rdstate() & ifstream::failbit) != 0)
   printf("failbit set\n");
```

check right after the `printf("fin is open\n");` line, and the `failbit` was set when the file is put into the folder during runtime.

Everything runs correctly when the file is in place before execution.

Comment: What happens if you put the file in place and *then* execute this code? Does it work as expected?

Comment: try to open tfile, not donefile - also: provide a self-contained example, fix warnings (long int requires `%ld`, not `%d`), gotos are a bad idea in general (use while or similar),  using ifstream and doing c-style-stringprocessing is like clubbing someone to death with a loaded Uzi

Comment: @NPE Yes, if the file was already in the folder, the program works as expected.

Comment: @Peter I've changed "donefile" to "tfile", and still got the same output. The program was written by someone else, originally using c-style programming. But there seems to be a bug with it, and so instead of using char arrays to store the filenames, I tried using std::string and ifstream. Then I got this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem.

The `failbit` was set after the first `fin.open` failed, and was never reset when the `fin.open` succeeded. Once I did a `fin.clear()` after `fin.close()` in the `else` loop, the program ran successfully.